# Non vector graphics display in a notebook

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, front-end, output, display

When I generate multiple scatter plots with a large number of points and display them as output, the notebook becomes very sluggish (I assume that this is because each plot has a huge number of points and the system has trouble with the graphics memory or something similar).

I would like to know if it is possible to set things up in such a way that the displayed figures are some sort of png but not vector graphics.

To be clearer: I wish to automatically replace the standard plot output with something like its screenshot. This is just about what I see in the notebook and has nothing to do with the nature of the `Graphics` object.

I looked around but couldn't find how to do it or whether it is possible.

Thanks!
Enrico

Comment: An alternative to a scatter plot for some cases is `SmoothDensityHistogram`

Answer (score 3):

> I wish to automatically replace the standard plot output with something like its screenshot.

Take a look at [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Post.html):

```
$Post = Replace[g : (_Graphics | _Graphics3D) :> Image[g]]
```

will convert any returned graphics or 3D graphics into an image.

Note this only works if the output is exactly a `Graphics`, and doesn't look inside.  So it would rasterize `Plot[x, {x,-2,2}]` but not `{Plot[x,{x,-2,2}]`.  To catch the latter, change the `Replace` above to a `ReplaceAll`

Comment: You could add `Legended` as well.  Personally I use something like `im = Image[Rasterize[#, "Image", ImageResolution -> 2*72], Magnification -> 1/2] &;` to get a nice retina rendering.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [`$DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) (*default setting for the option* `DisplayFunction` *in graphics functions*) to `Rasterize`:

```
$DisplayFunction = Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 100] &;

{Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}], 
 Histogram3D[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {500, 2}]], 
 BarChart[RandomInteger[10, {5, 3}]]}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) It sometimes work with `Legended` too, what is pleasant (but undocumented).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you ask for with the following:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[0.5], 1000000];
Image[ListPlot[data]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rasterize is an option. For example:

```
Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}], RasterSize -> 50]
```

gives a very coarse plot while

```
Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}], RasterSize -> 500]
```

gives better resolution.